# Print char pointer array in a struct with printf in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, c-strings

I am trying to print the names of my array with a for but the output gives me random letter and signs,
I cant cast it correctly to print the names of the struct.

```
typedef struct{
   // uint8_t name;
    char *name[100];
    char *lasTName[100];
}resFrame;

resFrame serverFrame;

for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
   printf("%s",(char *)&serverFrame.name[j]);  
}
```

Output:

```bash
�7��
```

I try with a for and with a other pointer but it gives me the same problem and sometimes a core dumped

Comment: Show how the data members are initialized.

Comment: delete the & ...?

Comment: How's `name ` allocated, most probably heap-allocated using `malloc()` ?? Better use `char **` to remove confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data member `name` declared like

```
char *name[100];
```

indeed contains pointers to strings then you need to write for example

```
printf("%s\n", serverFrame.name[j]);
```

The conversion specifier expects an argument of the type `char *`.

The expression used by you `&serverFrame.name[j]` has the type `char **`. Casting it to the type `char *` results in undefined behavior because the address of the pointer is considered by the call of `printf` as an address of the first element of a string.

Comment: If i try to printf("%s\n", serverFrame.name[j]); it gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: @cesar I showed you how correctly call printf. I do not know how the array of pointers actually initialized.

Comment: @cesar I advice you to close this question because as is it is answered and to ask a new question with at least the correct shown call of printf but including a minimal code that demonstrates how the data member were initialized. It seems pointers stored in the arrays are invalid.

Comment: @cesar Vlad from Moscow's answer is correct for fixing the printf problem. If after that fix you get a seg fault, it is a second problem. That second problem is likely due to incorrect setup of the severFrame object. The original post does not contain appropriate information relating to that.